# Extra loop in for-loop from exploded items

Tags: php, for-loop, explode

I have a list that is made with the sign | between each item. And here I want to loop through each of these items. Problem here is that the loop creates one extra loop with empty values. Here this extra loop should not be showed.

What am I doing wrong?

PHP:

```
    <?php   

    $variable['value'] = Something here|Another thing here

    $loop = explode("|", $variable['value']);

    for($x='0';$x<=count($loop);$x++) {

    echo "<span class='icon-caret-right'>";
    echo $loop[$x];
    echo "</span>";

    }               
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**: your condition in `for` loop is incorrect - `count` value is always equal to the maximum index + 1, so you can change it to `$x=0; $x<=count($loop)-1; $x++` or `$x=0; $x<count($loop); $x++`

**Second**: do not use `count` inside loop condition - cause it's being computed on every step, and you don't want it - use `foreach` instead.

**Third**: why `$x='0'`? `$x` shoud be an integer, so `$x=0`

Comment: Your third : $x='0' it does not matters. PHP take it as integer only.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi, ok, so technically it's true, but: one can use `$x=null;` or even simply `$x;`, but that *one* should write good code without such strange things like incrementing a string.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi sorry, I disagree again. It does matter when you see this in the code you need to maintain

Answer (score 0):

make for condition like below

```
for($x=0;$x<count($loop);$x++) {
```

Remove "<=" from condition.

```
for($x='0';$x<=count($loop);$x++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

since ur starting index is 0 so remove the "=" from the for condition or u can start the value of x from 1.both are same logically.

```
    for($x=0;$x<count($loop);$x++)
```

or

```
        for($x=1;$x<=count($loop);$x++)
```